# Image change even though it is unrelated

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have this script that detect the cookies and change the photo based on the language selected. When I try to click on the left button, the image change correctly, but when I click the right button, it changes the left button photo. Here is my code:-

**HTML**

```
<div id="slide_left" class="slide_left_close srl_menu">
<?php 
     if ($_COOKIE['language'] == 'indo') {
        echo '<button id="button_left" class="button-left" value="indo"><img id="bsright" src="'.$imgUrl.'images/indo/slide-left-button.png"/></button>';
     } else {
        echo '<button id="button_left" class="button-left" value="en"><img id="bsright" src="'.$imgUrl.'images/en/slide-left-button.png"/></button>';   
    }
?>
</div>

<div id="slide_right" class="slide_right_close srl_menu">
<?php 
    if ($_COOKIE['language'] == 'indo') {
        echo '<button id="button_right" class="button" value="indo"><img id="bsright" src="'.$imgUrl.'images/indo/slide-right-button.png"/></button>';
    } else {
        echo '<button id="button_right" class="button" value="en"><img id="bsright" src="'.$imgUrl.'images/en/slide-right-button.png"/></button>';
    }
?>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready( function(){

    /************************/
    /* SLIDE LEFT BUTTON */
    /***************************************/

    $("#button_left").on( "click", function(){
        var btnLeftLang = $(this).attr("value");
        /*Opens and closes the menu*/
        $("#slide_left").toggleClass("slide_left_open");
        if($("#slide_left").hasClass("slide_left_open")){
            /*If the menu is open, then:*/
            /*Change the menu button icon*/
            $("#bsleft").attr('src',imgPath+'images/'+btnLeftLang+'/slide-left-button.png');
         }else{
            /*If the menu is closed, change to the original button icon*/
            $("#bsleft").attr('src',imgPath+'images/'+btnLeftLang+'/slide-left-button.png');
         }
     });

    /************************/
    /* SLIDE RIGHT BUTTON */
    /***************************************/

    $("#button_right").on( "click", function(){
        var btnLang = $(this).attr("value");
        /*Opens and closes the menu*/
        $("#slide_right").toggleClass("slide_right_open");
        if($("#slide_right").hasClass("slide_right_open")){
            /*Change the menu button icon*/ 
            $("#bsright").attr('src',imgPath+'images/'+btnLang+'/slide-right-button.png');
        }else{
            /*If the menu is closed, change to the original button icon*/
            $("#bsright").attr('src',imgPath+'images/'+btnLang+'/slide-right-button.png');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Please check the code you showed under the **HTML** title. The first `IF` is not terminated properly and you have not turned the PHP interpreter off with a `?>`

Comment: @RiggsFolly Thanks. I have updated it.

Comment: So has that changed what happens??

Comment: @RiggsFolly Still the same.

Comment: All the `img` tags have the same ID.

Comment: @JonStirling Nice catch thanks!